# Cannot read properties of undefined - Vue error Just on production

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

When calling the exibirhorariosMonday function it gives an error that `SegundaC` is undefined, but only in production. Locally it works perfectly.

I tried to do the deployment in render and netfliy, and it keeps giving the same error: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SegundaC')`.

[image: Stacktrace of error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'SegundaC')"]

How do I solve this problem?

```
<template>
  <!-- SEGUNDA FEIRA -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <el-card class="box-card">
          <template #header>
            <div class="card-header">
              <span>Monday</span>

            </div>
          </template>
          <div class="demo-range">
            <el-time-picker @change="exibirhorariosMonday(1)" v-model="monday" is-range range-separator="To"
              start-placeholder="Start time" end-placeholder="End time" format="HH:mm" size="small" />
          </div>
          <el-checkbox v-model="SegundaC[0]" label="Lock" size="large" />
          <div>
            <el-tag v-if="parseInt(testem) != parseFloat(testem)" class="ml-2" type="danger">Minutes: {{ testem }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag v-else class="ml-2" type="success">Minutes: {{ testem }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag class="ml-2" type="success">Hours: {{ testem2.toFixed(2) }}</el-tag>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            </div>
        </el-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- TERCA FEIRA  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <el-card class="box-card">
          <template #header>
            <div class="card-header">
              <span>Tuesday</span>

            </div>
          </template>
          <div class="demo-range">
            <el-time-picker @change="exibirhorariosMonday(2)" v-model="tuesday" is-range range-separator="To"
              start-placeholder="Start time" end-placeholder="End time" format="HH:mm" size="small" />
          </div>
          <el-checkbox v-model="SegundaC[1]" label="Lock" size="large" />
          <div>
            <el-tag v-if="parseInt(testet) != parseFloat(testet)" class="ml-2" type="danger">Minutes: {{ testet }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag v-else class="ml-2" type="success">Minutes: {{ testet }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag class="ml-2" type="success">Hours: {{ testet2.toFixed(2) }}</el-tag>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            
          </div>
        </el-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- QUARTA FEIRA  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <el-card class="box-card">
          <template #header>
            <div class="card-header">
              <span>Wednesday</span>

            </div>
          </template>
          <div class="demo-range">
            <el-time-picker @change="exibirhorariosMonday(3)" v-model="wednesday" is-range range-separator="To"
              start-placeholder="Start time" end-placeholder="End time" format="HH:mm" size="small" />
          </div>
          <el-checkbox v-model="SegundaC[2]" label="Lock" size="large" />
          <div>
            <el-tag v-if="parseInt(testew) != parseFloat(testew)" class="ml-2" type="danger">Minutes: {{ testew }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag v-else class="ml-2" type="success">Minutes: {{ testew }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag class="ml-2" type="success">Hours: {{ testew2.toFixed(2) }}</el-tag>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            
          </div>
        </el-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Quinta Feira  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <el-card class="box-card">
          <template #header>
            <div class="card-header">
              <span>Thursday</span>

            </div>
          </template>
          <div class="demo-range">
            <el-time-picker @change="exibirhorariosMonday(4)" v-model="thursday" is-range range-separator="To"
              start-placeholder="Start time" end-placeholder="End time" format="HH:mm" size="small" />
          </div>
          <el-checkbox v-model="SegundaC[3]" label="Lock" size="large" />
          <div>
            <el-tag v-if="parseInt(testett) != parseFloat(testett)" class="ml-2" type="danger">Minutes: {{ testett }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag v-else class="ml-2" type="success">Minutes: {{ testett }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag class="ml-2" type="success">Hours: {{ testett2.toFixed(2) }}</el-tag>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            
          </div>
        </el-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

   <!-- Sexta Feira  -->

<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
        <el-card class="box-card">
          <template #header>
            <div class="card-header">
              <span>Friday</span>

            </div>
          </template>
          <div class="demo-range">
            <el-time-picker @change="exibirhorariosMonday(5)" v-model="friday" is-range range-separator="To"
              start-placeholder="Start time" end-placeholder="End time" format="HH:mm" size="small" />
          </div>
          <el-checkbox v-model="SegundaC[4]" label="Lock" size="large" />
          <div>
            <el-tag v-if="parseInt(testef) != parseFloat(testef)" class="ml-2" type="danger">Minutes: {{ testef }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag v-else class="ml-2" type="success">Minutes: {{ testef }}</el-tag>
            <el-tag class="ml-2" type="success">Hours: {{ testef2.toFixed(2) }}</el-tag>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
            
          </div>
        </el-card>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-sm-center">
      <div class="col-sm-auto">
 
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Hours Total</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" :value="totalh">
  </div>
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <span class="input-group-text" id="inputGroup-sizing-sm">Hours Total - Break</span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Small" aria-describedby="inputGroup-sizing-sm" :value="totalB">
  </div>

  
  
</div>
</div>
</div>

</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import moment from 'moment'
import {
  Check,
} from '@element-plus/icons-vue'
const monday = ref<[Date, Date]>([
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 7, 30),
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 16, 0),
])
const tuesday = ref<[Date, Date]>([
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 7, 30),
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 16, 0),
])
const wednesday = ref<[Date, Date]>([
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 7, 30),
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 16, 0),
])
const thursday = ref<[Date, Date]>([
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 7, 30),
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 16, 0),
])
const friday = ref<[Date, Date]>([
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 7, 30),
  new Date(2022, 9, 7, 16, 0),
])
const count = ref(1)
let testem = ref(510)
let testem2 = ref(8.5)
let testet = ref(510)
let testet2 = ref(8.5)
let testew = ref(510)
let testew2 = ref(8.5)
let testett = ref(510)
let testett2 = ref(8.5)
let testef = ref(510)
let testef2 = ref(8.5)
let totalh = ref(42.5)
let totalB = ref(37.5)
let totalTopM = ref(0)
let totalTopM1 = ref(0)
function exibirhorariosMonday (params)  {
  
  //console.log(ref(SegundaC[0]))
  if (params === 1) {
  this.SegundaC[0] = true;
  }
  if (params === 2) {
    this.SegundaC[1] = true;
  }
  if (params === 3) {
    this.SegundaC[2] = true;
  }
  if (params === 4) {
    this.SegundaC[3] = true;
  }
  if (params === 5) {
    this.SegundaC[4] = true;
  }
  var aM = moment(monday.value[1]);
  var bM = moment(monday.value[0]);
  this.testem = (aM.diff(bM, 'minutes'))
  this.testem2 = this.testem / 60;
  var aT = moment(tuesday.value[1]);
  var bT = moment(tuesday.value[0]);
  this.testet = (aT.diff(bT, 'minutes'))
  this.testet2 = this.testet / 60;
  var aW = moment(wednesday.value[1]);
  var bW = moment(wednesday.value[0]);
  this.testew = (aW.diff(bW, 'minutes'))
  this.testew2 = this.testew / 60;
  var aTT = moment(thursday.value[1]);
  var bTT = moment(thursday.value[0]);
  this.testett = (aTT.diff(bTT, 'minutes'))
  this.testett2 = this.testett / 60;
  var aF = moment(friday.value[1]);
  var bF = moment(friday.value[0]);
  this.testef = (aF.diff(bF, 'minutes'))
  this.testef2 = this.testef / 60;
  this.totalh = this.testem2 + this.testet2 + this.testew2 + this.testett2 + this.testef2
  let totalTopM = this.testem + this.testet + this.testew + this.testett + this.testef
  let totalTop = 42.5 - this.totalh
  let totalM = 2550 - totalTopM
  
  let valorrec = this.SegundaC.filter((value) => value === false).length;
  // valorrec = valorrec - 1
  // alert(valorrec)
  let divisaoS = totalM / valorrec
  let divisaoS1 = divisaoS / 60
  //  alert(totalTop)
  //  alert(totalM)
  // alert(divisaoS)
  // alert(divisaoS1)
  //  alert(SegundaC.value[1])
  //MUDAR SEGUNDA FEIRA
  if (SegundaC.value[0] === false) {
    //alert("nao entrou")
    var aM1 = moment(monday.value[1]);
    console.log(tuesday)
    let addHoraSegunda = moment(aM1).add(divisaoS, 'm');
    let horaSegunda1 = moment(addHoraSegunda).format('H');
    let minutoSegunda1 = moment(addHoraSegunda).format('m');
    monday.value[1] = new Date(2022, 9, 7, horaSegunda1, minutoSegunda1)
    this.testem2 = this.testem2 + divisaoS1;
    this.testem = this.testem + divisaoS;
  }
  //MUDAR TERCA FEIRA
  if (SegundaC.value[1] === false) {
    var aT1 = moment(tuesday.value[1]);
    console.log(tuesday)
    let addHoraTerca = moment(aT1).add(divisaoS, 'm');
    let horaTerca1 = moment(addHoraTerca).format('H');
    let minutoTerca1 = moment(addHoraTerca).format('m');
    tuesday.value[1] = new Date(2022, 9, 7, horaTerca1, minutoTerca1)
    this.testet2 = this.testet2 + divisaoS1;
    this.testet = this.testet + divisaoS;
  }
  //MUDAR QUARTA FEIRA
  if (SegundaC.value[2] === false) {
    var aW1 = moment(wednesday.value[1]);
    let addHoraQuarta = moment(aW1).add(divisaoS, 'm');
    let horaQuarta1 = moment(addHoraQuarta).format('H');
    let minutoQuarta1 = moment(addHoraQuarta).format('m');
    wednesday.value[1] = new Date(2022, 9, 7, horaQuarta1, minutoQuarta1),
      this.testew2 = this.testew2 + divisaoS1
    this.testew = this.testew + divisaoS
  }
  //MUDAR QUINTA FEIRA
  if (SegundaC.value[3] === false) {
    var aTT1 = moment(thursday.value[1]);
    let addHoraQuinta = moment(aTT1).add(divisaoS, 'm');
    let horaQuinta1 = moment(addHoraQuinta).format('H');
    let minutoQuinta1 = moment(addHoraQuinta).format('m');
    thursday.value[1] = new Date(2022, 9, 7, horaQuinta1, minutoQuinta1),
    this.testett2 = this.testett2 + divisaoS1
    this.testett = this.testett + divisaoS
  }
  //MUDAR SEXTA FEIRA
  if (SegundaC.value[4] === false) {
    var aF1 = moment(friday.value[1]);
    let addHoraSexta = moment(aF1).add(divisaoS, 'm');
    let horaSexta1 = moment(addHoraSexta).format('H');
    let minutoSexta1 = moment(addHoraSexta).format('m');
    friday.value[1] = new Date(2022, 9, 7, horaSexta1, minutoSexta1),
    this.testef2 = this.testef2 + divisaoS1
    this.testef = this.testef + divisaoS
    //this.totalh = this.testem2 + this.testet2 + this.testew2 + this.testett2 + this.testef2
    //let totalTopM = this.testem + this.testet + this.testew + this.testett + this.testef
  }
  this.totalh = this.testem2 + this.testet2 + this.testew2 + this.testett2 + this.testef2
  
  totalTopM1 = this.testem + this.testet + this.testew + this.testett + this.testef
  
  this.totalTopM1 = 2550 - this.totalTopM1 
  
  totalTop = 42.5 - this.totalh
  totalM = 2550 - totalTopM
  this.totalB = this.totalh - 5
}
// function exibirhorariosTerca() {
// var aT = moment(tuesday.value[1]);
// var bT = moment(tuesday.value[0]);
// this.testet = (aT.diff(bT, 'minutes'))
// this.testet2 = this.testet / 60;
// this.totalh = this.testem2 + this.testet2 + this.testew2 + this.testett2 + this.testef2 
// let totalTopM = this.testem + this.testet + this.testew + this.testett + this.testef 
// let totalTop = 42.5 - this.totalh
// let totalM =  2550 - totalTopM
// let divisaoS = totalM / 4
// }
function teste() {
  alert("working")
}
const SegundaC = ref([false, false, false, false, false])
// CARREGAMENTO DAS INFORMACOES AO ABRIR O SITE
</script>

<style>
.card-header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.text {
  font-size: 14px;
}
.item {
  margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.box-card {
  width: 480px;
}
.card-body {
  padding: 2px;
  border-style: dotted;
}
.demo-range .el-range-separator {
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Hello Augusto, you ll more chance to get answers with a testable snippet in jsFiddle or equivalent. also you can try to put your SegundaC const declaration on top of the script